# limit Concurrent logins in wicket application

Tags: java, spring, authentication, concurrency, wicket

I am developing a web application with Apache wicket(v 1.4) and spring(v 3.2) and i need to prevent users from logging in from two different 
places at same time.

I tried to do it with spring security concurrency control,i added the following in my xml

```
<security:http create-session="never" auto-config="true">
    <security:remember-me />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" />
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
            max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

but it doesn't seems to work.

Is there any wicket way to do it?Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Spring Security works fine, you just have to configure it correctly. What doesn't work as expected? How are you testing, note 2 tabs in a browsers aren't different locations!

Comment: i tried with two different browser

Comment: Define 2 different browsers... As in Chrome and Firefox or 2 browser windows? As the latter isn't different locations either.

Comment: One Chrome and One Firefox

Comment: concurrency control won't work in your sitation. You are running a stateless environment so no sessions, hence no way to control duplicate session instances. Concurrent session control only works when you have a http session else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the sessions/users "manually".

For example: use a Set in YourApplication.java to keep the currently logged in users' names. In your `signIn(String username, String password)` method check whether this username is already in the set. Override `Session#onInvalidate()` to remove the username from the Set.
Since this Set is a global state the access to it should be synchronized.